# Как сгруппировать листы в листе объектов

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

Не могу понять одну вещь... Допустим имеются такие классы:

```
public class SchoolData
{
   public string SchoolName {get;set;}
   public List<ChildData> Childs {get;set;}
}

public class ChildData
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
   public bool isMalchik {get;set;}
}
```

Мне поступает инфа о школах, и мне надо сгруппировать детей по девочкам и мальчикам и вывести их количество. Никак не получается...

```
public void SchoolInfo(List<SchoolData> Schools)
{
   var newData = Schools.GroupBy(s => s.ChildData.GroupBy(c => c.)) ??????????
}
```

Comment: Сначала вызови SelectMany на Schools - развернешь ChildData в перечисление и сможешь обратиться к отдельному объекту ученика. Потом групируй.

Comment: Вероятно ошибка при копировании кода, `Childs` это `ChildData` или `List<ChildData>`?

Comment: Необходимо именно сгруппировать или достаточно получить количество девочек и мальчиков?

Comment: @yolosora извините, это List<ChildData>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю в коде опечатка и в SchoolData, в Childs находится массив или список детей. (ChildData[])

Тогда подойдет подобное решение:

```
var newData = schools
            .SelectMany(x => x.Childs)
            .GroupBy(x => x.isMalchik)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key?"Man":"Woman", x => x.ToList());
```

На выходе получается словарь, где newData["Man"] - список мальчиков, а newData["Woman"] - список девочек.

Для вывода количества

Мальчиков - `Console.WriteLine($"{newData["Man"].Count}")`

Девочек - `Console.WriteLine($"{newData["Woman"].Count}")`

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно просто посчитать, то можно так. Надеюсь на меня не нападут фанаты небинарности гендера! Код с допущением, что `Childs` это все таки коллекция.

```
var kids = Schools.SelectMany(school => school.Childs).ToList();
int boys = k.Count(child => child.isMalchik);
int girls = k.Count - boys;
```